# select category list from t1, then select sum from t2 which has category list given to each data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables I am working with.

Table 1 has 10 categories, entries do not change. unless I change.

```
Cat_NO | Cause
1      = Animal
2      = Bird
3      = Bear
4      = Dog
5      = Snake
6      = Human
7      = Cow
8      = Car
9      = Fire
10     = Rain
```

Table 2 has data coming randomly when event occurs. unknown number of record/data.

has following fields

```
ID     Cat_Code   DateTime    Location    OtherField1   OtherField2

786      7           ...        ...           ...          ...
787      6           ...        ...           ...          ...
789      7           ...        ...           ...          ...
791      1           ...        ...           ...          ...
793      3           ...        ...           ...          ...
794      1           ...        ...           ...          ...
796      4           ...        ...           ...          ...
806      9           ...        ...           ...          ...
```

I am trying to write query that would give me total for all category in Table 1

Result should be

```
CAUSE       Total        Hours(I can do this) Field2(this too) Field3(This also)
Animal        2
Bird          0     
Bear          1
Dog           1
Snake         0
Human         1
Cow           2
Car           0
Fire          1
Rain          0
```

So far I've written

```
SELECT
       Cause
from Table1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select t1.cause, count(t2.cat_code) as total
from table1 t1 left outer join table2 t2 on t1.cat_no = t2.cat_code
group by t1.cause
```